# Load another apps Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 2 apps, app A and app B. App A saves some data in `SharedPreferences` using the following code:

```java
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("string1", string1);
editor.putBoolean("switch1", switch1);
editor.apply();
```

App B loads the App A's data through:

```java
Context con = createPackageContext("com.appApackage", 0);
SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
String text = pref.getString("string1","No Value");
boolean switchOnOff = pref.getBoolean("switch1", false);
```

The problem is that the app B loads data only once (only one time, after new fresh start), and if I change shared preferences in app A, the app B will load the same data it loaded the first time. i.e. it doesn't load new data until it's restarted again.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: SharedPreferences isn't reliable across processes (nor is recommended, going by the docs) - wrapping the preferences in a `ContentProvider` is something I've done before, and is a supported technique for accessing data across apps [link](https://medium.com/@TreeFrogApps/android-shared-preferences-so-whatever-happened-mode-multi-process-5f0b8dddbf4c)

Comment: @PPartisan you are appreciated for the comment and for pointing out to the solution. Thank you! :)